# Why does my bath fan timer will only work if the light is off?

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, timer

The switch and the timer are together in a two gang box. There is power to both however the fan timer will only work when the light is off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures and/or diagrams of **exactly how you wired it** are required to sort out **how it's wired so it doesn't do what you want it to do.**

Comment: I will take a SWAG, It sounds like the switch is a 3-way where a wire goes from the switch to the timer. That needs to come from the feed which will be connected to the identified terminal of th 3-way switch. If I am wrong pictures would be needed.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: How many wires originally came into the switch box? Was it 2 - a black and a white? With the light off and the fan running, does the light glow a little bit? If so then you have a 'switch loop' there and you can't run some other device from it, because you don't have neutral in the box (white does not mean neutral all the time).

Comment: I do have a black and a white coming into the box. With the light off the fan will run. The light doesn't glow at all.

Comment: @RandyPett can you get us a better-lit photo? It's hard to see what's going on in the top left of the box in the photo you provided...

Comment: @RandyPett -- where does the white wire from the left-hand switch go?

Comment: It's tied in with the rest of the whites

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: @RandyPett -- what make and model of timer are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is that you have the white from the switch tied in with the neutrals. Despite that wire being white it is actually the switched hot of a switch loop, not a neutral wire. You should connect the top screw of the switch to the white of the left cable (through a pigtail if desired) and mark it as "hot" with black tape. Do not tie this in with the rest of the white wires.

As it is wired now, when you close the switch (light on) it energizes not only the white wire of the left cable but also of the right cable, which is the neutral side of the timer. With both the hot and neutral side of the timer energized, there is no voltage drop across it to power it. When the switch is opened (light off) the timer's neutral side is no longer energized and the device is powered.

Answer (score 0):

It's working exactly as intended.

The light is turned off at 'switch-off' whereas the fan is delayed using an 'off-delay' timer.

Here's the schematic, courtesy [electroschematics.com](https://www.electroschematics.com/auto-bathroom-fan-control/)

[image]

When the switch S1 is closed, the light and the fan turn on.

When it is opened, the light goes out but the fan continues to run for the time selected by S2.

Comment: The problem is that I want both to be able to run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I only see two /2 cables in the box.  One cable, with white and black, coming in the top left, and another, also with black and white, coming in the top right.

Is there another cable entering the box that I'm not seeing?  If so I'll delete this answer.

If there are only two /2 cables entering the box, there are two possibilities:

1. they are both switch loops and you cannot use a timer like the one you have there because you don't have a neutral in the box.  You could use a mechanical, spring-operated, timer for the fan instead.  *There would be no wire nuts at all* in that case.  The light switch and the wind-up timer each have two terminals, and each cable gets connected to one device.
2. They are parallel /2s being used in lieu of a /4 to a combination fan/light.    The four wires (two blacks, two whites) are a live, a neutral, and a switched power back to each device.   If that's the case one of the whites is NOT neutral and should not be connected to the other neutrals the way you have done.  The white that *is* neutral should ONLY be connected to the timer's white conductor.

Determining which of these two situations you have is worthy of a separate answer, and probably a separate question so I'll leave it there for now.

EDIT: On further reflection, if your situation was #2 and you tied together all the whites that way, you'd have a short circuit and pop the breaker (hopefully).  So you probably have #1 and you want one of these for the fan ....

[image]

and if your timer there is one that does periodic or random fanning, you won't be able to do that.